# Google appengine datastore alternative?

Tags: google-app-engine, cassandra, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using Google AppEngine with build-in datastore. But, I want move all datastore to my new VPS.

I'll use Apache Cassandra. How to move from GAE Datastore to Apache Cassandra?

Comment: Have you thought about using Django (or whatever framework you like) on your new VPS?  That seems much easier than using an external datastore on GAE

Comment: are you trying to run your applications in app engine but have them access a cassandra server on your VPS?  Or are you trying to stop using app engine completely?

Comment: If you are going to use Cassandra it probably makes sense to move away from GAE completely and use either Amazon EC2 or managed cloud hosting solution like Rackspace, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're looking at a tool such as the bulk loader/downloader:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html

You'll want to export all your data into CSV, then write a script to import this into any new format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the bulk downloader if you are using the "High Replication" datastore.
You can use a manual aproach such as listing all your entities as dictionaries. You will have a JSON formatted string. By using this you can generate your entities again suitable for your new system.

Comment: @Nick; Just read the documentation. [link](http://code.google.com/intl/tr/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) _Note: This document applies to apps that use the master/slave datastore. If your app uses the High Replication datastore, it is possible to copy data from the app, but Google does not currently support this use case. If you attempt to copy from a High Replication datastore, you'll see a high_replication_warning error in the Admin Console, and the downloaded data might not include recently saved entities._

Comment: That doesn't mean it doesn't work - it just means that, as it disclaims, that the download might not be complete (which is an inevitable consequence of an eventually consistent datastore).

Comment: @Nick; Did you actually try it?

Comment: No, but the very bit of the doc you quote says "If your app uses the High Replication datastore, it is possible to copy data from the app".